# Destructor and constructor in C

Tags: c, initialization, destructor

I'm very new to C and I'm trying yet to fully understand it. I implemented a stack
but found trouble when making its destructor and it constructor/init.
Are these well done?
These are the typedefs for the structures used by the stack:

```
typedef struct Node{
    void* cargo;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct Stack{
    int size;
    Node* firstOut;
}Stack;
```

And these are the functions:

```
void newStack(Stack* stack){
    stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->firstOut = NULL;
    stack->size = 0;
}

void freeStack(Stack** stack){
    empty((*stack));
    free((*stack)->top);
    (*stack)->size = 0;
    free(stack);
}
```

My question is: are they well done? How would someone with proper experience do it?

Comment: Is there any particular reason your constructor needs to take a pointer argument?  Typically, constructors that take a pointer are really "initializers", as they don't actually *allocate* any memory, but only *initialize* the variables inside the structure to their default values.

Comment: What does your compiler tell you about this code? Specifically about `free((*stack)->top);`?

Comment: I want to make many stacks

Comment: "But found trouble". Please tell us more specifically what troubles you have encountered.  It's hard to tell with such incomplete code. But `newStack` looks wrong. `stack` is local to the function so the buffer allocated and assigned to it will be lost as soon as the function exits. Need to either pass in  a `Stack **` or return `stack`.

Comment: Also, `free(stack)` looks wrong, as it won't free the same thing you allocated in `newStack`.

Comment: @J. Morgan Lieberthal im sorry, thats what i tried to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and more urgently about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  At the moment, your constructor constructs but then leaks the memory it allocated/constructed (and the code that called the constructor is left without the data that it requested the constructor to construct).  This is a problem.  You seem to have changed your mind about the name of the pointer variable in the stack structure.  Please show code that compiles — do not show code that does not compile unless your question is about why the code does not compile.

Comment: is your `empty()` function checks if stack is empty or it is responsible for freeing all the stack elements?

Comment: please check example stack implementation [here](https://github.com/Mrunmoy/Stack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newStack` should simply return the stack pointer that it allocates. It doesn't need to receive a `Stack*` as an argument.

```
stack *newStack() {
    Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (stack != NULL) { // allocation successful
        stack->firstOut = NULL;
        stack->size = 0;
    }
    return stack;
}
```

and `freeStack` should receive a stack pointer as argument, it doesn't need double indirection.

```
void freeStack(Stack *stack) {
    empty(stack);
    free(stack->firstOut); // This isn't done by empty()?
    free(stack);
}
```

There's no need to set `stack->size` before freeing, since the memory is going to go away and the value it contains is irrelevant.

Comment: The constructor should check the result of the `malloc()` before dereferencing the result.